# SFML animation without keyboard input

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

I'm working on a project at the moment which is basically a visualisation of Sort algorithms to explain how they work (rather than an overview). I'm new to using the SFML (or even OpenGL) and have limited experience with the library, but what I'm trying to do is move the drawn sprite to different locations to show the sorting. I've looked over tutorials and examples, but they all take in keyboard input to move the sprite - something that isn't used in this project. Does anyone know exactly how to achieve this?

Here's the current code:

## DrawCups.h

```
class DrawCups
{
public:
    DrawCups(sf::RenderWindow& window);
    ~DrawCups();

    void loadImage(const char* pathname, sf::Texture& texture, sf::Sprite& sprite);

    void drawCup1();

private:
    sf::RenderWindow& _window;
};
```

## DrawCups.cpp (selected function)

```
void DrawCups::drawCup1()
{
    // load our image
    sf::Texture cup1;        // the texture which will contain our pixel data
    sf::Sprite cup1Sprite;         // the sprite which will actually draw it
    loadImage("./images/InsertionSort/red_cup_1.png", cup1, cup1Sprite);
    cup1Sprite.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(150, 230));
    _window.draw(cup1Sprite);
}
```

## main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1366, 768), "Sorting Algorithm Visualisation: SFML");
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        window.clear(sf::Color::White);
        DrawCups drawToWindow(window);;
        drawToWindow.drawCup1();
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with updating the image every time you need to redraw it?

Comment: It needs to have a smooth movement from it's original location to the sorted area. Re-drawing the sprite makes the animation choppy.

Comment: You have to redraw the sprite to make it move. If the animation is too choppy you either aren't redrawing it fast enough or you are changing its position too quickly.

Comment: Could you possibly show an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the image before the loop and update it before you draw it.

```
DrawCups drawToWindow(window); //Constructor creates the sprite

while (window.isOpen())
{
    ...
    drawToWindow.update(); //Update the position

    //Redraw
    window.clear(sf::Color::White);
    drawToWindow.drawCup1();
    window.display();
}
```

I'm not sure what type of movement you want but the update function can be something like this:

```
void DrawCups::update()
{
    sf::Vector2f pos = this->cup1Sprite.getPosition();
    pos.x++; //Move 1 pixel to the left
    this->cup1Sprite.setPosition(pos);
}
```

Obviously change the movement to suit your needs. Make smaller/larger updates if it's moving too fast or slow.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the example. :)

Comment: Hmm, the code you provided, just makes the screen flash - not move the element itself. I've tested it by using a larger pixel range than just 1.

Comment: I can't test my code at the moment so there may be a mistake. Are you sure you're updating the position correctly? Make sure your draw function doesn't reset the position like it did before.

Comment: Maybe I'm using the position wrong then, because I've tried it with .rotate and it works fine. I'm currently using pos.x+10; - is this incorrect?

Comment: You probably meant `pos.x+=10;`? `pos.x+10` doesn't do anything with the result.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. But even that isn't moving the sprite. Also, how would I go about stopping the movement of the sprite once it's at the desired location? Say, start location is 100,100 and end location is 50,100?

Comment: You should try to figure it out yourself and post another question if you are stuck. There are probably examples online (not specific to SFML).